# Flask not reading environment variables with supervisor, gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to deploy a flask app to my Cent OS server but I think it can't read the environment variables that are being set by supervisor.

Here's my supervisor conf for the flask app

```
[program:philms]
environment=PHILMS_SECRET="supersecretkey",PHILMS_API_SECRET="shmickles"
command = gunicorn philms.app:create_app\(\) -b 0.0.0.0:5000
directory = /sites/philms
user = wilson
```

I've tried setting the variables in my `.bashrc` but that didn't work. And I can't see anything wrong with my supervisor conf.

Comment: Did you reload the configuration? Just editing the file doesn't work.

Comment: I'd been restarting it but I've just reloaded it now and I got this error ```philms: ERROR (no such file)```. Does that mean there's a problem with my conf file?

Comment: Fixed the error in my config and now it's all working. Thanks man! Much appreciated.