# Flask virtual environment and environment variables

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, supervisord, python-venv

To get `gunicorn` under `supervisord` to use the **virtual** environment `/home/ubuntu/venv/bin` it is not necessary to seek a judicious place to put `source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate`. It is sufficient to write:

```
[program:hello]
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 hello:app
directory=/home/ubuntu/hello/
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/venv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)"
```

in `/usr/supervisor/hello.conf`.

The next task is to bring in a whole slew of environment **variables**. One way is to laboriously augment the `supervisord` config file as follows.

```
[program:hello]
...
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/venv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)",SECRET_KEY="%(ENV_SECRET_KEY)",DATABASE_URI="%(ENV_DATABASE_URI)",etc1,etc2,etc3
```

Is there a way to bring in the environment variables in one shot (after they're initialized in, say, `~/.profile`?

Related: 
[1](https://serverfault.com/a/745252/294014), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611920/704972), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199329/704972), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36572205/704972), [5](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/), [6](https://youtu.be/p0iQfT85IvM), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704891/704972)

Comment: If you launch gunicorn at the command line, does it work?

Comment: Does `supervisord` inherit your environment when it starts, or does it create its own? Entering the venv just sets some environment variables, so you need to ensure those are properly set in `supervisord`'s environment.

Comment: @SuperShoot Ah! good point. No, it doesn't. Can you suggest another lead on the road to debugging this?

Comment: @chepner What do you mean by "inherit the enviroment"? Regardless of whether the (bash) shell is or is not in the venv, it fails. `supervisord`'s `environment` is, IIUC, for environment variables, not for a Python virtual environment.

Comment: Entering a Python virtual environment does little more than add the appropriate directory to `PATH` in your environment. If `supervisord`'s `PATH` does not include `/home/ubuntu/venv/bin`, then it won't be using the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: @chepner Interesting.. so that means that I can replace any attempt at `source ..activate` with a `supervisord` environment setting inside the `[program:hello]` block, no? That does not help.

Comment: What if you return `os.environ['PATH']` from the view so you can inspect it?

Comment: I see that this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/704972) method (which otherwise works correctly) is misleading in this case. If I return `sys.version`, I see that I am indeed in the virtual environment in this toy/hello application, but not in my actual application. So my isolation for the purpose of this question is not complete.

Comment: @SuperShoot os.environ['PATH'] shows the venv's path. That's a good starting point to see what's happening in the bigger app.

Comment: Don't use supervisord? :)

Comment: @hd1 and not use a process controller at all? If you are using and are happy with a competitor (http://supervisord.org/glossary.html#term-daemontools), please share your experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recipe:

Write the environment variables in a file `/home/ubuntu/prog/.env`.

```
export FLASK_APP=/home/ubuntu/prog/hello.py
export SECRET_KEY=ABCD
export DATABASE_PASSWORD=EFGH
```

Use `dotenv`'s `load_dotenv` to load the environment variables.

```
from flask import Flask
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = Flask(__name__)
dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
    DATABASE_PASSWORD = environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
    return SECRET_KEY + DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

Write a file `/etc/supervisor/hello.conf`.

```
[program:hello]
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 hello:app
directory=/home/ubuntu/prog
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/prog/hello_out.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/prog/hello_err.log
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/ubuntu/prog/hello_supervisord.log
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
```

Load the environment and point to the the app.

```
source /home/ubuntu/prog/.env
```

The environment variables are now loaded,

```
$ export | grep SECRET
declare -x SECRET_KEY="ABCD"
```

and they *will* be passed to the sub-process without messing with `supervisord`'s `environment=`.

Launch `supervisord` in the foreground to confirm all is well.

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -n -edebug -c /etc/supervisor/hello.conf
```

Confirm from another shell that all is well.

```
$ curl localhost:8000
ABCDEFGH
```

Kill `supervisord`. Since it's in the foreground, it's enough to CTRL-c it.

Launch `supervisord` as a daemon.

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/hello.conf
```

Keep an eye on the three log files `prog/hello_out.log`, `prog/hello_err.log`, and `prog/hello_supervisord.log`.

Perhaps the most important point is to avoid using `supervisord`'s `environment=`. SO chatter suggests that it handles commas, quotation marks, tabs, even newlines. Empirically, this doesn't hold (at least for `supervisord` 3.3.5), and the documentation does not settle it one way or the other. The two lines [942-943](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/options.py#L942)
seem to be where the [parsing](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/options.py#L2170) happens, if someone cares to investigate the insufficiency of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To bring in the environment variables in one shot, permanently, securely you have to add following lines to *.bashrc* in $HOME directory.
For this open the *.bashrc* file in your home directory with your favorite code editor:

`nano .bashrc`

Add the following line somewhere in your *.bashrc* file:

`export SECRET_KEY="YOUR SECRET KEY."`

Now to use this SECRET_KEY in flask you have to import os module and make use of it like this.

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    return SECRET_KEY
```

Hope this helps.